# Play-jongo unresolved dependency

Tags: mongodb, playframework, playframework-2.0, jongo

I'm trying to use Play-jongo https://github.com/alexanderjarvis/play-jongo with Play 2.0. The Build.scala looks like this.

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
  "uk.co.panaxiom" %% "play-jongo" % "0.2"
)

val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = JAVA).settings(
  resolvers += ("GitHub Play Repository" at "http://alexanderjarvis.github.com/releases/")     
)
```

However, Play can't seem to find the dependency.

```
[warn] ==== GitHub Play Repository: tried
[warn]   http://alexanderjarvis.github.com/releases/uk/co/panaxiom/play-jongo_2.9.1/0.2/play-jongo_2.9.1-0.2.pom
```

...

```
[error] {file:/home/steven/Projects/project-escape/server_play2/}Perk/*:update: sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: uk.co.panaxiom#play-jongo_2.9.1;0.2: not found
```

Anyone know where the repository is?

Thanks

Comment: The repository layout is strange, you should raise an issue to the author on Github.

Comment: Thanks, have added an issue here
https://github.com/alexanderjarvis/play-jongo/issues/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this for resolver as per author of the module.

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("My GitHub Play Repository", url("http://alexanderjarvis.github.com/releases/"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)
```